# chef mongodb user_management (create admin and other users)

Tags: mongodb, chef-infra, chef-recipe

I'm relatively new to chef and am in the process of using the edelight mongodb cookbook. I've got the process of actually creating a standalong mongodb instance working fine. It's understanding how to use the subsequent user_management recipe to create the initial admin user and regular users.

When I add "default['mongodb']['config']['auth'] = true" to the attributes/default.rb file, and run the mongodb::default recipe, the db is created and authentication is on.

However when I run the mongodb::user_management recipe I get this error every time. Clearly I'm doing something wrong, but being new to editing chef/ruby files I can't determine what's failing. Looks like I might need to work within the users.rb attribute file?

===================================================

## Error executing action `add` on resource 'mongodb_user[admin]'

### NameError

uninitialized constant Mongo::MongoClient

Answer (score 0):

The edelight cookbook has been unmaintained for quite some time now.  Chef-Brigade is attempting to take over maintenance on the cookbook until a new owner can be found.

https://github.com/chef-brigade/mongodb-cookbook

There is work being implemented to fix some of the user_management issues. I am not 100% sure the current state of the user_management fixes but you would likely be better off starting with that cookbook and reporting any issues to the team there so they can work to resolve.  There is active development taking place.

I would be glad to help you debug the issue if it persists on the chef-brigade flavor of the cookbook as we can actively make changes to resolve any issues.

Comment: Thanks! Well I'm using this new cookbook. When I add in "default['mongodb']['config']['auth'] = true" to the default.rb file and upload the cookbook and run the recipe user_management, I'm still getting this error.

 Recipe: mongodb::user_management
* mongodb_user[admin] action add
================================================================================
Error executing action `add` on resource 'mongodb_user[admin]'
==========================================================
 
NameError
---------
uninitialized constant Mongo::MongoClient

Comment: @GTaber Can you open an issue on the github for that repo?  We can triage and keep discussion going there.  I think it might be related to https://github.com/chef-brigade/mongodb-cookbook/pull/39 but I would need a bit more info from you to confirm.

When submitting the issue can you make sure to include the full stacktrace and any other information that may be relevant including run_list and any attributes which would impact this execution.